# How to make a Perforce changelist restricted under certain conditions?

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to make a changelist restricted if any of the files in it match a certain pattern? I'd like to use this to protect private internal projects from external contractors.

I know that the contractors won't be able to see the files if they don't have access in the protections, but I'd rather not have to rely on everyone sanitizing their checkin comments.

Comment: Seems like a good use for a trigger. Or you could put a broker in front and do this sort of thing in your broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I did this, but as I recall the trick is to set up a very simple trigger that forces *all* changelists to be restricted. Assuming you are already using protections, your users will then see only the changelists whose files they can see; all other changelists (and their descriptions) will be hidden from them.

Comment: Needed to revisit this issue and found a solution at http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/1902-trigger-to-set-all-changelists-to-restricted-solved/